# how to set CSS attributes of label in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating a static using Html.LabelFor(...).
I have to set Name attribute of the label dynamically using JQuery.

Comment: The `<label>` tag doesn't *have* a `name` attribute, so you'll find it quite impossible to set using jQuery. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @Aaronaught: I am creating a complex model for a financial project. You will get better idea from http://www.google.com/finance/stockscreener. Look for the criteria section, try to add new criteria. Look at the first default parameter - Market Cap. I am creating an empty row in a table and setting the contents for the respective controls in that row using jquery. I am able to set the contents for TextBox but not for labels.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the css class, and set inline styles and any other attribute (even non-existant ones like name) using the htmlAttributes parameter provided in one of the overloads of LabelFor

ie

```
<%: Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Title, 
                           new { style="xyz", @class="abc", @name="MyTitle" }) %>
```

this would create a label something like:

```
<label for="Title" style="xyz" class="abc" name="MyTitle">Title</label>
```

The reason for the @ before class, is that "class" is a reserved word in c#, so you need to qualify it using the @ symbol.

Comment: Thanks James, but the second parameter is for text. I have already tried this but goes into error. The htmlAttributes can be applied to text box but not for label.

Comment: MVC3 does not include this overload, later versions do. This response explains how to add the necessary overloads as extension methods: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9885580/1617125

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question and comments together, you're just trying to change the *text* of a label.  The MVC `LabelFor` turns into an HTML `<label>` and that doesn't have any attributes like a text box does.

If you need to change it with JS/jQuery then give it an ID and use the `html` method.

Markup:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Something, new { id = "somethingLabel" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Something)
```

jQuery:

```
$("#somethingLabel").html("New Label Text");
```

You could also use `text` instead of `html` - the difference is just that it escapes the input.