# How to extend MVC3 Label and LabelFor HTML helpers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, extension-methods

`Html.Label` and `Html.LabelFor` helper methods do not support the htmlAttributes parameter like most of the other helpers do.  I would like to set the `class` however.  Something like this:

```
Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label" })
```

Is there an *easy* way of extending Label/LabelFor **without** resorting to copying and extending  the ILSpy disasm output of those methods?

Answer (score 25):

You can easily extend the label by creating your own LabelFor:

Something like this should do what you need

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
{
  return LabelFor(html, expression, new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
}

public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
  ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
  string htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
  string labelText = metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(labelText))
  {
    return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
  }

  TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("label");
  tag.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
  tag.Attributes.Add("for", html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(htmlFieldName));
  tag.SetInnerText(labelText);
  return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

**Update**
To use the extension method just created in your project, add this line in your `Views\web.config`

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
    <add namespace="MyProject.Helpers" />   <-- my extension

    ...

 </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Comment: I know, but I'm trying to avoid replicating the disassembled / original source output.  The original code consists of 22 methods, do this properly I would have to override them all.

Comment: no. you simply create your extension project and insert in your web.config the call to your project.

Answer (score 6):

```
public static class LabelExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
        string labelText,
        object htmlAttributes
    )
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<TModel, TProperty>(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        var htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        return LabelHelper(htmlHelper, metadata, htmlFieldName, labelText, htmlAttributes);
    }

    public static IHtmlString Label(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string expression, string labelText, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromStringExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        return LabelHelper(htmlHelper, metadata, expression, labelText, htmlAttributes);
    }

    private static IHtmlString LabelHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, string htmlFieldName, string labelText, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        string str = labelText ?? (metadata.DisplayName ?? (metadata.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split(new char[] { '.' }).Last<string>()));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }
        TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("label");
        tagBuilder.Attributes.Add("for", TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(htmlFieldName)));
        var attributes = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
        tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(attributes);
        tagBuilder.SetInnerText(str);
        return new HtmlString(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
}
```

and then:

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.SomeProperty, null, new { @class = "foo" })
```

or:

```
@Html.Label("SomeProperty", null, new { @class = "foo" })
```

Comment: Sorry mate if I didn't make myself clear.  I've done this (copying MVC source and extending it), however it's something I would like to avoid for a number of reasons. Also I like to keep things DRY.  I was hoping there would be something more elegant.

Comment: Sorry there's nothing out there allowing you to do this. The built-in helper is not extensible and it has the attributes hardcoded.

Comment: How can I get the compiler to disambiguate between myProject.Helpers.LabelExtensions.LabelFor and 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.LabelExtensions.LabelFor (needed for other stuff on the page)?

Comment: @Ungaro did you find an answer to your question?

Comment: @nicola deep No. I rewrote my extensions to reference Lable and LableFor and use those throughout my views.

Comment: @Ungaro I'm not sure I understand what you mean... are you saying you ended up doing: /@Html.LableFor and changed all your views?