# Helper for a LabelFor which wraps an HTML tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have some entities with long names and I'd like to be able to abbreviate them in labels, using the HTML `abbr` tag. I make use of DataAnnotations to provide a DisplayName value for the property in the view model (or the entity class).

I've been manually doing this like:

`<label class="myClass"><abbr title="@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Ssn)">SSN</abbr> @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Ssn)</label>`

but it's becoming a pain. I'd like to design a helper with the following syntax.

`@Html.AbbrLabelFor(m => m.Ssn, "SSN")`

and outputs:

`<label for="Ssn"><abbr title="Social Security Number">SSN</abbr></label>`

where "Social Security Number" is the DisplayName value, and the second argument in the helper tag is the abbreviation text. So basically just adding the second argument to the mix.

The examples I've seen tend to ditch the HtmlAttributes and such, and I'd like to retain that functionality, as in:

`@Html.AbbrLabelFor(m => m.Ssn, "SSN", new { @class="myClass" })`

How do I extend the existing, full-featured LabelFor to implement this, a DfnLabel, etc.?

Comment: This might help a bit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885548/how-to-extend-mvc3-label-and-labelfor-html-helpers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your helper needs to look like

```
public static MvcHtmlString AbbrLabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string abbreviation, object htmlAttributes)    
{
    ModelMetadata metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
    string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)       
    TagBuilder abbr = new TagBuilder("abbr");
    abbr.MergeAttribute("title", metaData.GetDisplayName());
    abbr.InnerHtml = abbreviation;
    TagBuilder label = new TagBuilder("label");
    label.MergeAttribute("for", name);
    label.MergeAttributes(HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
    label.InnerHtml = abbr.ToString();

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(label.ToString());
}
```

Edit (with overloads)

```
public static MvcHtmlString AbbrLabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string abbreviation)
{
    ModelMetadata metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
    string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    return AbbrLabelHelper(helper, metaData, name, abbreviation, null);
}

public static MvcHtmlString AbbrLabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string abbreviation, object htmlAttributes)
{
    ModelMetadata metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
    string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    return AbbrLabelHelper(helper, metaData, name, abbreviation, htmlAttributes);
}

private static MvcHtmlString AbbrLabelHelper(HtmlHelper helper, ModelMetadata metaData, string name, string abbreviation, object htmlAttributes)
{
    TagBuilder abbr = new TagBuilder("abbr");
    abbr.MergeAttribute("title", metaData.GetDisplayName());
    abbr.InnerHtml = abbreviation;
    TagBuilder label = new TagBuilder("label");
    label.MergeAttribute("for", name);
    label.MergeAttributes(HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
    label.InnerHtml = abbr.ToString();
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(label.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Beautiful. I have to pass null for HtmlAttributes if I don't want them, but that's fine by me. Thanks so much.

Comment: Just create another overload. I'll update the answer shortly.

Comment: I realized that shortly after I commented; thanks for updating it though.