# mvc helper for rendering custom textbox

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Inside razor view I'm using html helper

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.YearsInService, new { @class = "col-lg-1" })
```

which renders following html

```
<input id="YearsInService" class="col-lg-1" type="text" value="" name="YearsInService" 
       data-val-required="The YearsInService field is required." 
       data-val-number="The field YearsInService must be a number." 
       data-val="true" disabled="disabled">
```

since I want to implement validation with tooltip messages [like this](http://blog.johnnyreilly.com/2013/08/using-bootstrap-tooltips-to-display.html)
I need solution input element to be rendered like this

```
<input 
  data-msg-number="The field YearsInService must be a number."       
  data-rule-number="true"    
  data-rule-required="true"   
  id="YearsInService" name="YearsInService" type="text" value="" />
```

> question is: how can build custom mvc helper for rendering second html
>   code in razor view?

Comment: Do you mean a HtmlHelper extension method - i.e. to use like `@Html.ToolTipTextBox(m => m.YearsInService)`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke can be, yes

Comment: And do you also want the `data-val` attributes necessary for client side validation?

Comment: yes, with maybe with one more possibility data-rule-date="true"

Comment: Need a break, but will add and answer showing how to do it with and extension method in 30 min or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a HtmlHelper extension method to output your html.

```cs
public static MvcHtmlString ToolTipTextBoxFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, 
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    attributes.Add("data-msg-number", "The field YearsInService must be a number.");
    attributes.Add("data-rule-number", true);
    ... other 'fixed' attributes as required
    return InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(helper, expression, attributes);
}
```

and then in the view

```cs
@ToolTipTextBoxFor(m => m.YearsInService, new { @class = "col-lg-1" })
```

and of course you could create other overloads to match the `TextBoxFor()` method overloads.

**Edit**

From your comments, you also want to generate `data-rule-` attributes based on the properties validation attributes. To do this, you can get the [ModelMetatdata](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata(v=vs.118).aspx)

```cs
ModelMetadata metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
```

and then check its properties

for example

```cs
if (metaData.IsRequired)
{
    attributes.Add("data-rule-required", true);
}
```

Comment: great, is there any way to improve this to use model data annotation attributes, for exapmle if it's decorated with Required to include data-rule-required in this helper, ...

Comment: I guess you haven't tried it yet. The `data-val` attributes will be added :) - its calling the `InputExtensions.TextBoxFor()` method which adds everything.

Comment: Also refer last part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26955073/converting-asp-net-mvc-razor-helper-function-into-a-method-of-a-helper-class/26955246#26955246) for adding the namespace to your `web.config.cs` file to avoid `@using` statements in your view

Comment: Just read your comment again - did you mean `data-val-required` or `data-rule-required`?

Comment: I mean data-rule-required

Comment: I also guessing that you want to include `data-rule-number="true"` if the property is a numeric type? If so, you could first look at the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749966/c-sharp-how-to-determine-whether-a-type-is-a-number) and you can pass `metadata.ModelType` to Jürgen Steinblock's solution

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood what you want, I am sure you need [Editor Template](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom html attributes using one of the TextBoxFor overloads:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.YearsInService, new { data_msg_number = "The field YearsInService must be a number.", data_rule_number="true" })
```

If you are OK with using `EditorFor` instead of `TextBoxFor` then I would suggest creating editor templates. [There is nice article describing the basics](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/extending-editor-templates-for-asp.net-mvc/).

If you would like to create a new `Html.MySuperTextBoxFor` extension method, then check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885548/how-to-extend-mvc3-label-and-labelfor-html-helpers).