# Label with extra attributes using ASP.NET HTML Helpers

Tags: html, asp.net, html-helper

I would like to know if it's possible to generate the label tag below using HTML Helpers:

```
<label class="myClass" attr1="attr1Value" attr2="attr2Value" attr3="attr3Value">labelText</label>
```

It's basically a standard label tag having 3 extra attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**htmlAttributes**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions.label(v=vs.118).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LabelExtensions.Label%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary%7BSystem.String,System.Object%7D%29) parameter of `@Html.Label` or `@Html.LabelFor`

```
@Html.Label("YourLabel", new { attr1 = "attr1Value", attr2 = "attr2Value" })
```

When using `class` or other reserved words use at `@`

```
@Html.Label("YourLabel", new { @class = "classname" })
```

When using attributes with dashes `-`, such as data attributes, use underscores `_` which end up being converted to dashes `-`

```
@Html.Label("YourLabel", new { data_url = "myurl" })
```

> However, I think support for `htmlAttributes` in `Html.Label` and
>   `Html.LabelFor` was only added in MVC4, for earlier versions of MVC
>   you can write your own extension method.
>
> [How to extend MVC3 Label and LabelFor HTML helpers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885548/how-to-extend-mvc3-label-and-labelfor-html-helpers)

Answer (score 0):

Using the HtmlHelper its possible to add custom attributes to any Element.

```
@Html.Label("Content", new { attr1= "attr1" })
```

but you need to add @ to attributes that are keywords e.g. class