# How to Overload MVC HtmlHelper Extension Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to register a Custom MVC HtmlHelper extension.

I have created the appropriate static class and static method for my extension method but how do I register/import/use that namespace in my view so it shows up as an extension method for some given method, for `@Html.SomeMethod`

In Asp.Net WebForms I can simply add:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MyExtensionNamespace.MyExtensionClassName" %>
```

How do I do the same with MVC so my extension method for my Html Helper will resolve correctly and my method will show up in IntelliSense?

To be clear, I am only trying to add extensions to existing methods so that they will accept different arguments as parameters, such as `System.Reflection.PropertyInfo`

For example, I want to an an extension method for `System.Reflection.PropertyInfo` to `@Html.Label`

```
    @{
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(MyClaimDto).GetProperties();
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        if (prop.PropertyType != typeof(MyNamespace.DynamicDictionary))
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(prop, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.Editor(prop.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.Hidden("Utility." + prop.PropertyType.FullName, new { @class = "form-control" } )
                    @Html.Hidden("PlaceHolder." + prop.Name, new { @class = "form-control" } )
                    @Html.ValidationMessage(prop.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }


}
```

But VS tells me I still have an error under my call that says the Type Arguments could not be inferred:

[image]

Here's the code for my extension:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
namespace EFWCF.Extensions
{
    public static class LabelExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<PropertyInfo, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<PropertyInfo> html, Expression<Func<PropertyInfo, TValue>> expression)
        {
            var type = expression.Type;
            MvcHtmlString result = new MvcHtmlString(type.FullName);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

If I give the method a different name it will resolve:

```
public static MvcHtmlString PropertyLabelFor<PropertyInfo, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<PropertyInfo> html)
{
    var type = expression.Type;
    MvcHtmlString result = new MvcHtmlString(type.FullName);
    return result;
}
```

And:

```
 @Html.PropertyLabelFor(prop)
```

But I want to be able to call existing @Html methods for additional types.

Comment: In Razor you can use `@using MyExtensionNamespace.MyExtensionClassName`. Note that your extension method needs to be a static `MvcHtmlString` method.

Comment: It is, let me try that.

Comment: No go, I will update my question.

Comment: What kind of error text you get on reddish underline in `@using EFWCF.Extensions.LabelExtensions` from your picture?

Comment: Thanks @TetsuyaYamamoto First error fixed, Was using `Namespace.ClassName` when it should have been just `Namespace` for the import. +1 for that answer. But I have updated question again. Its complaining type couldn't be inferred and should be explicitly defined.

Comment: You need to give other method name for custom extension method since `LabelFor` is already reserved for `System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.LabelFor`. Your custom method trying to override standard `LabelFor` defined with `TModel` and it simply doesn't work. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196290/how-can-i-override-the-html-labelfor-template to override standard `LabelFor`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Please add your comments as an answer so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage* means that there was generic type mismatch occurred during assigning an identifier as a method type argument. Here your custom extension method defines `System.Reflection.PropertyInfo` as substitution of `TModel`:

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<PropertyInfo, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<PropertyInfo> html, Expression<Func<PropertyInfo, TValue>> expression)
{
    var type = expression.Type;
    MvcHtmlString result = new MvcHtmlString(type.FullName);
    return result;
}
```

And this is a standard `HtmlHelper.LabelFor` method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
{
   ...
}
```

Based from my observation, Razor seems to use `HtmlHelper.LabelFor` instead of using its custom extension method overload, hence there in view page you're tried to assign `PropertyInfo` as `expression` argument on standard `LabelFor` which expecting a lambda expression, resulting CS0411 error.

To solve this, either change custom extension method name to another valid name (avoiding naming conflict) or create an overload for standard `LabelFor` with type checking against `System.Reflection.PropertyInfo` like this example:

```
// note that you still require to insert PropertyInfo as a lambda expression here
public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
{
    var modelType = typeof(TModel);
    var propertyInfo = typeof(System.Reflection.PropertyInfo);
    if (modelType.IsAssignableFrom(propertyInfo))
    {
        var type = expression.Type;
        var tag = new TagHelper("label");
        var attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        tag.MergeAttributes(attributes);
        tag.SetInnerText(type.FullName); // set inner text between label tag
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
    else
    {
        // return another value, e.g. return MvcHtmlString.Empty
    }
}
```

**NB:** If you taking first option by using different method name than `LabelFor` & don't want to use lambda expression as `PropertyInfo` assignment, simply remove `Expression<Func<PropertyInfo, TValue>>` and use `PropertyInfo` directly as given below:

```
public static MvcHtmlString PropertyLabelFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, PropertyInfo propertyInfo, object htmlAttributes)
{
    var type = propertyInfo.GetType();
    var tag = new TagHelper("label");
    var attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    tag.MergeAttributes(attributes);
    tag.SetInnerText(type.FullName); // set inner text between label tag
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

Afterwards, use reference of your helper namespace at web.config inside `Views` directory so that you don't need to use `@using` directive in view page:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" />
        ...
        <add namespace="EFWCF.Extensions.LabelExtensions" /> <-- add this line
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Additional references:

[How can I override the @Html.LabelFor template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196290/how-can-i-override-the-html-labelfor-template)

[How to extend MVC3 Label and LabelFor HTML helpers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885548/how-to-extend-mvc3-label-and-labelfor-html-helpers)

Answer (score 3):

You can refer the namespace in two ways like below:

Directly in the View:

```
@using YourProject.HtmlHelpers;
```

or you could add a reference to that namespace within your `Views/web.config` file so that there is no need to add the `using` to the top of the view :

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      <!-- Reference here -->
      <add namespace="YourProject.HtmlHelpers" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. What's weird is my web.config doesn't even have that section. I am using the first method currently but I can't seem to overload.

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins it is the web.config. in the Views folder

Comment: Did not know that. Great Info. As to the underlying problem, I now understand I can't accomplish what I was attempting.

Comment: Great update. I know that you you can add `.config` files at the folder level but was unaware that `MVC` registered imports like this.

Comment: yes you can make use of webconfig in the view folder..:). And thanks you very much @Nkosi for pointed out that. Happy sharing.:)